# TypeError: write_points() got multiple values for argument 'time_precision' to insert dataframe into influxdb using python

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, influxdb, influxdb-python

I am trying to insert a dataframe into influxdb using python. I have followed this [link](http://influxdb-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html) . and I tried the same code. But I am getting the following error.
**"TypeError: write_points() got multiple values for argument 'time_precision'"**
I am new to influxdb and i can not figure out where i am doing the mistake.
I checked the connection and while inserting one point using json then it is inserting but when i am trying dataframe then only i am getting this error. My code is

```
from influxdb import InfluxDBClient
from influxdb import DataFrameClient
import pandas as pd
Host_IP = 'XXXXXXXX'
Port = XXXX
User = 'XXXX'
Password = 'XXX'
DB_Name = 'XXXX'
client = InfluxDBClient(Host_IP, Port, User, Password,DB_Name)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=list(range(30)),index=pd.date_range(start='2014-11-16',periods=30, freq='H'))
client.write_points(df, 'demo',{'k1': 'v1', 'k2': 'v2'}, time_precision=None, protocol='json')
```

I have also followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46575210/trouble-inserting-dataframe-into-influxdb-using-python) but nothing changed. Please help me to figure out the error. I am using python 3.6.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out why it was not working for me. I used the regular InfluxDBClient which I imported one line after the DataFrameClient

```
client=DataFrameClient(...)
client=InfluxDBClient(...)
```

After fixing this it all worked for me. I can see you have also imported the wrong client. Use the DataFrameClient and you should be fine.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](//stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: well thanks but as I wrote I cant comment, which I think is very inconvenient!

Comment: Not having enough rep to comment is not an excuse to post comments as answers.